# \aftergroup recursion strange expansion

Tags: tex-core

I'm trying to write a recursion using `\aftergroup` which would do something at end of every group. 
mwe:

```
\protected\def\printB{B \aftergroup\printB}
$$\halign \bgroup ${#}$\cr a \printB \crcr\egroup$$
\bye
```

eTex breaks with error `! Missing $ inserted.` Some how it happens that `\aftergroup` takes `$` and not only `\printB` macro. Is it possible to protect such an expansion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\aftergroup` only takes one token `\printB` but the recursion never ends, if you add a `\message`

```
\protected\def\printB{\message{.}B \aftergroup\printB}
$$\halign \bgroup ${#}$\cr a \printB \crcr\egroup$$
\bye
```

you see

```
 . . . . . .

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
\bye ->\par
```

It's called 6 times before it fails.

The extra `$` that finally causes an error is because the aftergroup-inserted token is inserted after `\crcr` so starts a new halign row so the `{#}` template has been inserted but you never end that row until you finally hit `\bye` and error.

You see essentially the same error with a no `\aftergroup` but an explicit `B` after `\crcr`

```
\halign {
${#}$\cr a \crcr B}$$
\bye
```

produces

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
\bye ->\par 
            \vfill \supereject \end 
l.4 \bye

? x
```

Comment: Answer didn't solved the recursion, but now it's clear what's happening. I'll except the answer.

Comment: @Linuxss I didnt suggest a fix as I couldn't guess what you wanted it to do:-) perhaps a global definition of `\def\printB{}` so it's harmless and then define it to br `\aftergroup` inside the halign cell template so any that aftergroup outside the cell expand to nothing. But the code will always break somewhere there are so many internal groups in things like section headings etc who knows how many places this would insert tokens in unfortunate places

Comment: What I wanted to do was locally set `\postdisplayskip=1000` for some display math that I wouldn't need to write it outside of display and embrace everything. So I tried at `\everydisplay` register group level and with some command written before the end of display start the `\aftergroup` recursion. Where I was searching for wanted group level and there I would be assigning `\postdisplaypenalty`. So now I redone it with global assignments.

Comment: I guess the first comment means that you are an "except"ional TeXnician.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following example:

```
\tabskip=30pt
\halign{{$#$x}&u#v\cr
  a\aftergroup b&c\cr
  a\aftergroup \aftergroup \aftergroup b&c\cr
  a\aftergroup \aftergroup \aftergroup \aftergroup
   \aftergroup \aftergroup \aftergroup b&c\cr
}

\bye
```

[image]

In the first case, the `b` is printed outside of math mode. In the second case it is printed after the group around `$#$x`. In the third case it is printed after the implicit group around the `\halign` cell, so ending up as the first item in the next cell.

You define `\printb` to do `b\aftergroup\printb` in the hope that when TeX arrives at the top level the `\aftergroup` has no effect, but…

Just in the same way the third case prints `b` in the *second* cell of the align, in your case the `b` will appear when TeX hasn't yet seen the `}` ending the `\halign`. Since `b` is not `\omit`, a new cell is started, which forms a group…

A simpler example is

```
\def\printb{b\printb}
\halign{#\cr a\printb\cr}

\bye
```

The problem is exactly the same.

If you think that `\crcr` ends `\halign` you're unfortunately wrong. Its function is to execute `\cr` (the primitive `\cr`) provided it doesn't follow one (primitive) `\cr` command. In that position it is the same as `\cr`.